# Redirect within component Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple method that at the end of it I want to redirect to another component:

```
export class AddDisplay{
  display: any;

  addPairTo(name: string, pairTo: string){
    this.display = {};
    this.display.name = name;
    this.display.pairTo = pairTo;

  }
}
```

What I wanna do is at the end of the method redirect to another component:

```
export class AddDisplay{
  display: any;

  addPairTo(name: string, pairTo: string){
    this.display = {};
    this.display.name = name;
    this.display.pairTo = pairTo;

    this.redirectTo('foo');
  }
}
```

How do I achieve this in Angular 2?

Comment: I can only think of routing. You can do that with [navigate](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Router-class.html)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

first configure routing

```
import {RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
```

and

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/addDisplay', component: AddDisplay, as: 'addDisplay' },
  { path: '/<secondComponent>', component: '<secondComponentName>', as: 'secondComponentAs' },
])
```

then in your component import and then inject Router

```
import {Router} from 'angular2/router'

export class AddDisplay {
  constructor(private router: Router)
}
```

the last thing you have to do is to call

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('<pathDefinedInRouteConfig>');
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['<aliasInRouteConfig>']);
```

Comment: FYI: `navigateByUrl` doesn't accept an array. Just a single string.

Comment: How do I reload the view? `navigate` and `navigateByUrl` seem to change change the url but the components bound to the route are not reloaded.

Comment: Note: This answer addresses a beta or release-candidate version of Angular 2 and is no longer applicable for Angular 2 final.

Answer (score 8):

@kit's answer is okay, but remember to add `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` to providers in the component. Then you can redirect to another page within `ngOnInit` method:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router'

@Component({
    selector: 'loginForm',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.navigate(['./SomewhereElse']);
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: This answer addresses a beta or release-candidate version of Angular 2 and is no longer applicable for Angular 2 final.

Comment: @jbandi could you please then provide an updated answer please?

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me Angular cli 6.x:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private artistService: ArtistService, private router: Router) { }

  selectRow(id: number): void{
       this.router.navigate([`./artist-detail/${id}`]);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
callLog(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/getstudent/'+this.login.email+'/'+this.login.password)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.getstud=data as string[];
        if(this.getstud.length!==0) {
            console.log(data)
            this.route.navigate(['home']);// used for routing after importing Router    
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi PYRO BUG, welcome. Please consider adding an explanation.