# how to redirect page in angular 2

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, router

Current page is http://localhost:4200/#/workrec-list

I want to go to http://localhost:4200/#/single

How to do that in angular?

I have

```
this.router.navigate(['/single'], {queryParams: {month: this.data.month}});
```

But it doesn't work. And has error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '/single'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect within component Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896407/redirect-within-component-angular-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093654/error-uncaught-in-promise-error-cannot-match-any-routes-angular-2)

Comment: Have you configured routing for your project?

Comment: Have you set route for 'single' in your project?

Answer (score 1):

```
    This code will help you to solve redirection problem of yours i am also attaching jsfiddle[link text](http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/25081/)


            <html ng-app="myApp">
            <head>
            </head>
            <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
                <p> <a href="https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/"><button>Click me to redirect from template</button></a></p>
                <p ng-click="myFunction()"> <button>Click me to redirect from controller</button></p>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
                app.controller('myCtrl',function($window,$scope){
                    $scope.myFunction = function(){
                    $window.location.href = 'http://delmarts.com/'; //You should have http here.
                    }
                });
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using **RoutingModule** We’re going to use 2 components in this example: **Component1** and **Component2** create a file called **app.routing.ts**:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Component1 } from './component1.component';
import { Component2 } from './component2.component';
const appRoutes: Routes = 
       [{ path: 'component1', component: Component1 },
        { path: 'component2', component: Component2 }];
 export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
 export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

I’ve defined the paths **/component1** and **/component2** which will allow me to redirect to both my components.

Next we have to import the routing configuration on the app.module.ts as follows:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders }  from './app.routing';
import { Component1 } from './component1.component';
import { Component2 } from './component2.component';

@NgModule({
imports:      [ BrowserModule, routing ],
declarations: [ AppComponent, Component1, Component2],
providers:    [appRoutingProviders],
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

now you can redirect by passing the path to the **routerLink** attribute of a regular link:

```
<a routerLink="/component1" >Component 1</a>
<a routerLink="/component2" >Component 2</a>
```

i have tried this example hope this would help....